# Create iframe content using django ajax and render_to_string

Tags: ajax, django, iframe, dynamic, render-to-string

I'm trying to create embeddable content similar to how twitter allows websites to embed tweets.

For example, twitter allows the user to copy paste a stub blockquote and javascript that, upon running the js, replaces the blockquote with an iframe of content.

I've done something similar (I'm using django)

```
<blockquote class="embedded">
  <p>placeholder text</p>
</blockquote>
<script async src="{% static 'widgets.js' %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The widgets.js script then makes an ajax call to a django view method that calls render_to_string and loads the desire HTML for the iframe. If simple HTML is returned then everything works perfectly because it merely requires something like `iframe.get()[0].contentWindow.document.write(content)`

But here's my problem. The HTML I want to load requires DataTables and DataTables is supposed to init a table inside $(document).ready().
Because this is iframe content, document.ready() will never be called (as far as I'm aware). At the moment I've been able to init the DataTable by placing my javascript at the very end of the HTML but there's no guarantee that the html would be fully loaded when that init call is done.

Ultimately the issue is timing. I need the dynamically generated iframe content (loaded with ajax via a django template) to execute its javascript *before* it's then loaded into the iframe.

Is there a way to enforce this timing?

Comment: Why not just set the iframe src to a view's url? Then you would have a complete request lifecycle. You could show a loader until the Data Table is through running its `init()`

Comment: You could also call the iframe's view url within your main view and get the resulting html, which can then be passed to the context.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the src attribute because the page being created is done so via an ajax POST call. In other words the html that is being added to the iframe doesn't exist as a page in its own right. Perhaps I'm trying to over-complicate things because I see youtube's embedded links use an iframe's src attr, unlike twitter, which doesn't.